# Convergence of the sum of the subsequence $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty } 2^{k}x_{n_{k}}$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

Let $\{x_{n}\}$ be a sequence such that $\lim_{n \to ∞}x_{n}=0$. Prove that there exists a sub sequence $\{x_{n_{k}}\}$ of $\{x_{n}\}$ such that $\sum_{k=1}^{\infty } 2^{k}x_{n_{k}}$
converges and $|\sum_{k=1}^{\infty } 2^{k}x_{n_{k}}|$≤1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the $x_n$ go to zero, you can pick arbitrarily small elements of the sequence if you make $n$ large enough.

Let $y_1$ be equal to the first $x_n$ such that $|2x_n|<\frac{1}{2}$.

Let $y_2$ be equal to the next $x_n$ such that $|2^2x_n|<\frac{1}{2^2}$.

Let $y_3$ be equal to the next $x_n$ such that $|2^3 x_n|<\frac{1}{2^3}$.

Continue in this fashion, defining the general $y_k$ term similarly. Then the $y_k$ form a subsequence of the $x_n$, and $\sum_1^\infty 2^k y_k$ converges absolutely to a number $a$ with $|a|\le 1$.

Comment: I don't get how $y_{k}$ forms a subsequence